# Excel conditional formatting formula inconsistencies in colour coding

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a problem where I am colour coding according to a set of formulae, where the format for the final formula is set to red fill with a clear font, but it shows up as orange with a clear font.

[image]

the formula for the red option is: =LEFT(J5,SEARCH("/",J5,1)-1)/MID(J5,SEARCH("/",J5,1)+1,LEN(J5)-SEARCH("/",J5,1))<0.6
with the font set to clear and the fill to red

the other formulae are similar for values =1 for green and <1 for orange.

also note the anomaly in the column references, the data was originally in column J but was cut and pasted to column E to try to make the example more amenable to formatting for this post.

also note that using the stop after tick box doesn't usually seem to work when used

Thank you

Comment: I have just tried reversing the order of the formulae which has worked!

Comment: Yes I had already cleared all additional formatting, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Can your 0/5 and 5/5 be 0 and 1? There is a **Fraction** number format that will allow 0, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1 in those F5:F10 cells and they will be true fractions as numbers (negating the necessity for any text parsing) but whole numbers are reverted to integers.

Comment: btw, your `LEN(J5)-SEARCH("/",J5,1)` could just be `9` (assuming that the denominator is never greater than 9 digits)

Comment: The **Stop if true** is largely to provide backwards compatibility to pre-2007 worksheets (e.g. .XLS/.XLM). Afaik, it has never worked properly in 2007-2016 CFRs.

Comment: I had earlier investigated the horde of rules that were originally included after copying and pasting from another spreadsheet and deleted all except those that were relevant.  However, it does appear that copying or moving a conditional format to other cells often doesn't always end up appearing to specify the new cells to which it applies or even the ones that are used as references, though there aren't any of those in this case.  Please note again that reversing the order did provide a solution, though why it didn't work the other way around escapes me

Comment: the rules have generally appeared to work from top to bottom, such that the most recent rule takes precedence

Answer (score 0):

Your rules for Red (<0.6) will always cast TRUE for Orange too (<1)...

You will want to change the Orange Rule to be between 0.6 and 1:-

```
=AND(LEFT(J5,SEARCH("/",J5,1)-1)/MID(J5,SEARCH("/",J5,1)+1,LEN(J5)-SEARCH("/",J5,1))>=0.6,LEFT(J5,SEARCH("/",J5,1)-1)/MID(J5,SEARCH("/",J5,1)+1,LEN(J5)-SEARCH("/",J5,1))>1)
```